# can anyone tell me what is the difference between read() and readline();?

Tags: java

```
package com.learn.java;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class BufferReaderInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferreaderIn = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter your Name");
        String Name = bufferreaderIn.readLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(bufferreaderIn.readLine());

        System.out.println("Enter your salary");
        int sal = bufferreaderIn.read();

        System.out.println("Hi, I'm " + Name + " my age is " + age
                + " and my salary is " + sal);
    }

}
```

When I enter salary using `obj.read();` it is not giving the right output.

With that can anyone tell me what is the difference between `read()` and `readline()`?

Comment: read() read one character, readLine() reads a whole line. For more detail I suggest you read the documentation for this class. If you read the documentation you can save yourself a lot of wasted time. As you need to read a number, most likely you want to use `Scanner` instead of BufferedReader.

Answer (score 3):

As from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) of `BufferedReader`, we have this for [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()):

> Reads a single character.

And this for [`readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

So, set apart the details of when a line is considered to be terminated, the difference is that the first one read a single character whilst the second one read a whole line.

Answer (score 2):

`readLine()` reads line till it sees `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`, while `read()` read one character.